# Prove that if a sequence is Cauchy, then it is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have a question about the proof of Cauchy implying boundness. The proof argues that after $N$ terms, the sequence is bounded, i.e. we could have $|s_n - s_N| < 1, \forall n > N \Rightarrow s_n \in (s_N - 1, s_N + 1)$.

But to argue $\{s_n : n < N\}$ is bounded, the proof simply says that because it is finite, namely we can have $ |s_n| \leq \max\{ |s_1|, \ldots, |s_N| \}$. I don't quite understand this part. What if $s_{i} = \infty, i<N$? Then the sequence is not bounded.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The $s_i$ are, presumably, defined to be real numbers, which $\infty$ is not.

Comment: I may misunderstand this part, but if $s_i$s are not extended to $\infty$, then the original sequence $\{s_i\}$ are all finite ($<\infty$) by themselves, ain't they?

Comment: The fact that every term in a sequence is finite does not imply the sequence is bounded. Consider $s_n=n$ for instance.

Comment: Did you try to find a sequence for which $s_i=\infty$. Try to find a Cauchy sequence for which your case is possible.

Comment: What about sequence $\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\}$ but with $\frac{1}{2^2}$ replace with $\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

The author of that proof is just saying that if you have a finite set $A$ and if $a\in A$, then $|a|\leqslant\max\{|x|\mid x\in A\}$. Note that, since $A$ is a finite set of numbers (in particular, none of them is $\infty$), it has a maximum. And then each of its elements is smaller than or equal to that maximum.

Comment: But if $s_i < \infty$, shouldn't the original sequence $\{s_i\}$ be finite ($<\infty$) already? Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to say that a sequence is finite?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant each term of the sequence is smaller than $\infty$.

Comment: It is a sequence of real numbers. Therefore, each of its terms is smaller than $\infty$.